# How to replace jmeter jtl httpSample/httpSample subchild value with parent value using java

Tags: java, regex, xml, jmeter, xml-parsing

I try to generate jmeter report using standard jmeter report template XSL(jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl) but somehow, report is not able display the sub-child for httpSample/httpSample as a breakdown of the httpSample.

Is there anyway to display sub-child httpSample/httpSample result as a breakdown of it's parent httpSample?

I have an idea to replace sub-child lb value with it's parent lb value in order to make it unique. But how can i do it as I am new to java/regex/XSL.

```
below is original jtl
```

```
<sample t="1605" it="15032" lt="0" ct="0" ts="1567595832665" s="true" lb="A02 Landing" rc="200" rm="Number of samples in transaction : 3, number of failing samples : 0" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="" by="70695" sby="3136" ng="2" na="2">
  <httpSample t="649" it="0" lt="629" ct="440" ts="1567595837679" s="true" lb="A02.01 /abcd/login.action?do=Login" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="2094" sby="1671" ng="2" na="2">
    <httpSample t="629" it="0" lt="629" ct="440" ts="1567595837679" s="true" lb="https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/login.action?do=Login" rc="302" rm="Moved Temporarily" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="856" sby="1001" ng="2" na="2"/>
    <httpSample t="18" it="0" lt="18" ct="0" ts="1567595838310" s="true" lb="https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/HandlerInit.action?do=Redirect" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="1238" sby="670" ng="2" na="2"/>
  </httpSample>
  <httpSample t="549" it="0" lt="533" ct="137" ts="1567595843333" s="true" lb="A02.02 /abcd/HandlerLogin.action?do=InitLoad" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="34332" sby="794" ng="2" na="2"/>
  <httpSample t="407" it="0" lt="402" ct="332" ts="1567595848894" s="true" lb="A02.03 /abcd/message_board.action" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="34269" sby="671" ng="2" na="2"/>
</sample>
<sample t="5863" it="15038" lt="0" ct="0" ts="1567595835027" s="true" lb="A03 Landing 2" rc="200" rm="Number of samples in transaction : 3, number of failing samples : 0" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="" by="70695" sby="3136" ng="2" na="2">
  <httpSample t="609" it="0" lt="290" ct="142" ts="1567595840037" s="true" lb="A03.01 /abcd/login.action?do=Login2" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="2094" sby="1671" ng="2" na="2">
    <httpSample t="290" it="0" lt="290" ct="142" ts="1567595840037" s="true" lb="https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/login.action?do=Login2" rc="302" rm="Moved Temporarily" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="856" sby="1001" ng="2" na="2"/>
    <httpSample t="318" it="0" lt="318" ct="0" ts="1567595840328" s="true" lb="https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/HandlerInit.action?do=Redirect2" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="1238" sby="670" ng="2" na="2"/>
  </httpSample>
  <httpSample t="2064" it="0" lt="1323" ct="342" ts="1567595845660" s="true" lb="A03.02 /abcd/HandlerLogin.action?do=InitLoad" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="34332" sby="794" ng="2" na="2"/>
  <httpSample t="3190" it="0" lt="1302" ct="333" ts="1567595852737" s="true" lb="A03.03 /abcd/message_board.action" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="34269" sby="671" ng="2" na="2"/>
</sample>
```

```
expected result as below. It's will be few hundred thousand row need to be replace. Is there any way to replace it?
```

```
<sample t="1605" it="15032" lt="0" ct="0" ts="1567595832665" s="true" lb="A02 Landing" rc="200" rm="Number of samples in transaction : 3, number of failing samples : 0" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="" by="70695" sby="3136" ng="2" na="2">
  <httpSample t="649" it="0" lt="629" ct="440" ts="1567595837679" s="true" lb="A02.01 /abcd/login.action?do=Login" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="2094" sby="1671" ng="2" na="2">
    <httpSample t="629" it="0" lt="629" ct="440" ts="1567595837679" s="true" lb="A02.01 https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/login.action?do=Login" rc="302" rm="Moved Temporarily" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="856" sby="1001" ng="2" na="2"/>
    <httpSample t="18" it="0" lt="18" ct="0" ts="1567595838310" s="true" lb="A02.01 https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/HandlerInit.action?do=Redirect" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="1238" sby="670" ng="2" na="2"/>
  </httpSample>
  <httpSample t="549" it="0" lt="533" ct="137" ts="1567595843333" s="true" lb="A02.02 /abcd/HandlerLogin.action?do=InitLoad" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="34332" sby="794" ng="2" na="2"/>
  <httpSample t="407" it="0" lt="402" ct="332" ts="1567595848894" s="true" lb="A02.03 /abcd/message_board.action" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="34269" sby="671" ng="2" na="2"/>
</sample>
<sample t="5863" it="15038" lt="0" ct="0" ts="1567595835027" s="true" lb="A03 Landing 2" rc="200" rm="Number of samples in transaction : 3, number of failing samples : 0" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="" by="70695" sby="3136" ng="2" na="2">
  <httpSample t="609" it="0" lt="290" ct="142" ts="1567595840037" s="true" lb="A03.01 /abcd/login.action?do=Login2" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="2094" sby="1671" ng="2" na="2">
    <httpSample t="290" it="0" lt="290" ct="142" ts="1567595840037" s="true" lb="A03.01 https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/login.action?do=Login2" rc="302" rm="Moved Temporarily" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="856" sby="1001" ng="2" na="2"/>
    <httpSample t="318" it="0" lt="318" ct="0" ts="1567595840328" s="true" lb="A03.01 https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/HandlerInit.action?do=Redirect2" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="1238" sby="670" ng="2" na="2"/>
  </httpSample>
  <httpSample t="2064" it="0" lt="1323" ct="342" ts="1567595845660" s="true" lb="A03.02 /abcd/HandlerLogin.action?do=InitLoad" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="34332" sby="794" ng="2" na="2"/>
  <httpSample t="3190" it="0" lt="1302" ct="333" ts="1567595852737" s="true" lb="A03.03 /abcd/message_board.action" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="34269" sby="671" ng="2" na="2"/>
</sample>
```

Comment: You should ideally not use regex here, but rather use an XML parser (Java has a number of good libraries which do this).

Comment: hi good day tim, java is a good idea. but how can XML parser know there there is sub-child for httpSample and replace with it's parent lb value. Not all the httpSample do have child, only those httpSample contains child will be replace with parent label.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, regular expression wouldn't be the best way to solve this problem, since it seems pretty complicated.

---

Being said that, parents have two spaces at start of the line and "subchilds" seems to have four and you can use that as a left boundary, if you want to, and design any expression that you have to, such as:

```
^\s{2}<httpSample\s+.*?lb="(\S*).*[\r\n]^\s{4}<httpSample\s+.*?lb="([^"]*)"
```

just as an example.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "^\\s{2}<httpSample\\s+.*?lb=\"(\\S*).*[\\r\\n]^\\s{4}<httpSample\\s+.*?lb=\"([^\"]*)\"";
        final String string = "<sample t=\"1605\" it=\"15032\" lt=\"0\" ct=\"0\" ts=\"1567595832665\" s=\"true\" lb=\"A02 Landing\" rc=\"200\" rm=\"Number of samples in transaction : 3, number of failing samples : 0\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-1\" dt=\"\" by=\"70695\" sby=\"3136\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\">\n"
             + "  <httpSample t=\"649\" it=\"0\" lt=\"629\" ct=\"440\" ts=\"1567595837679\" s=\"true\" lb=\"A02.01 /abcd/login.action?do=Login\" rc=\"200\" rm=\"OK\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-1\" dt=\"text\" by=\"2094\" sby=\"1671\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\">\n"
             + "    <httpSample t=\"629\" it=\"0\" lt=\"629\" ct=\"440\" ts=\"1567595837679\" s=\"true\" lb=\"https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/login.action?do=Login\" rc=\"302\" rm=\"Moved Temporarily\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-1\" dt=\"text\" by=\"856\" sby=\"1001\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\"/>\n"
             + "    <httpSample t=\"18\" it=\"0\" lt=\"18\" ct=\"0\" ts=\"1567595838310\" s=\"true\" lb=\"https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/HandlerInit.action?do=Redirect\" rc=\"200\" rm=\"OK\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-1\" dt=\"text\" by=\"1238\" sby=\"670\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\"/>\n"
             + "  </httpSample>\n"
             + "  <httpSample t=\"549\" it=\"0\" lt=\"533\" ct=\"137\" ts=\"1567595843333\" s=\"true\" lb=\"A02.02 /abcd/HandlerLogin.action?do=InitLoad\" rc=\"200\" rm=\"OK\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-1\" dt=\"text\" by=\"34332\" sby=\"794\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\"/>\n"
             + "  <httpSample t=\"407\" it=\"0\" lt=\"402\" ct=\"332\" ts=\"1567595848894\" s=\"true\" lb=\"A02.03 /abcd/message_board.action\" rc=\"200\" rm=\"OK\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-1\" dt=\"text\" by=\"34269\" sby=\"671\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\"/>\n"
             + "</sample>\n"
             + "<sample t=\"5863\" it=\"15038\" lt=\"0\" ct=\"0\" ts=\"1567595835027\" s=\"true\" lb=\"A03 Landing 2\" rc=\"200\" rm=\"Number of samples in transaction : 3, number of failing samples : 0\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-2\" dt=\"\" by=\"70695\" sby=\"3136\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\">\n"
             + "  <httpSample t=\"609\" it=\"0\" lt=\"290\" ct=\"142\" ts=\"1567595840037\" s=\"true\" lb=\"A03.01 /abcd/login.action?do=Login2\" rc=\"200\" rm=\"OK\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-2\" dt=\"text\" by=\"2094\" sby=\"1671\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\">\n"
             + "    <httpSample t=\"290\" it=\"0\" lt=\"290\" ct=\"142\" ts=\"1567595840037\" s=\"true\" lb=\"https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/login.action?do=Login2\" rc=\"302\" rm=\"Moved Temporarily\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-2\" dt=\"text\" by=\"856\" sby=\"1001\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\"/>\n"
             + "    <httpSample t=\"318\" it=\"0\" lt=\"318\" ct=\"0\" ts=\"1567595840328\" s=\"true\" lb=\"https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/HandlerInit.action?do=Redirect2\" rc=\"200\" rm=\"OK\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-2\" dt=\"text\" by=\"1238\" sby=\"670\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\"/>\n"
             + "  </httpSample>\n"
             + "  <httpSample t=\"2064\" it=\"0\" lt=\"1323\" ct=\"342\" ts=\"1567595845660\" s=\"true\" lb=\"A03.02 /abcd/HandlerLogin.action?do=InitLoad\" rc=\"200\" rm=\"OK\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-2\" dt=\"text\" by=\"34332\" sby=\"794\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\"/>\n"
             + "  <httpSample t=\"3190\" it=\"0\" lt=\"1302\" ct=\"333\" ts=\"1567595852737\" s=\"true\" lb=\"A03.03 /abcd/message_board.action\" rc=\"200\" rm=\"OK\" tn=\"Thread Group 1-2\" dt=\"text\" by=\"34269\" sby=\"671\" ng=\"2\" na=\"2\"/>\n"
             + "</sample>";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match:   <httpSample t="649" it="0" lt="629" ct="440" ts="1567595837679" s="true" lb="A02.01 /abcd/login.action?do=Login" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="2094" sby="1671" ng="2" na="2">
    <httpSample t="629" it="0" lt="629" ct="440" ts="1567595837679" s="true" lb="https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/login.action?do=Login"
Group 1: A02.01
Group 2: https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/login.action?do=Login
Full match:   <httpSample t="609" it="0" lt="290" ct="142" ts="1567595840037" s="true" lb="A03.01 /abcd/login.action?do=Login2" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="2094" sby="1671" ng="2" na="2">
    <httpSample t="290" it="0" lt="290" ct="142" ts="1567595840037" s="true" lb="https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/login.action?do=Login2"
Group 1: A03.01
Group 2: https://10.111.11.111:7351/abcd/login.action?do=Login2
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eOdQym/1). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/eOdQym/1debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: good day emma, thank you for guiding me on the logics. but how can i replace httpSample/httpSample lb value with the value we get for matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2);